# Apigen fails to generate documentation for replaced libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, documentation

According to the codeigniter documentation, this is how we should replace the native libraries with out own one:

> Simply by naming your class files identically to a native library will
>   cause CodeIgniter to use it instead of the native one. To use this
>   feature you must name the file and the class declaration exactly the
>   same as the native library.

but when I give two classes the same name, Apigen fails to generate documentation for both of them, displaying this error message instead:

> Documentation of this class could not be generated.
>
> Class was originally declared in application/libraries/Session.php and
>   is invalid because of:
>
> Class was redeclared in system/libraries/Session.php.

(In this case I'm trying to replace the session class).

Which one is guilty in this case, codeigniter or Apigen? And how is it possible to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `--exclude` parameter to skip the classes you replaced under `system`.
Manually listing the overridden classes can be boring, but you can script this easily:

```
$app_files = glob('application/{core,libraries}/*.php', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($app_files as $file) {
    $sys_file = preg_replace('/^application\//', 'system/', $file);
    if (is_file($sys_file)) {
        print  ' --exclude '.realpath($sys_file); // looks like it has to be a full path
    }
}
print "\n";
```

and calling the generation in the CI root directory like this:

```
$ apigen `php overriden_classes.php` --source . --destination apigenout
```